# Remove repeated header lines from a txt file but keep the first header row

Tags: python

I have multiple `.txt` files that are pipe delimited with a header row, but the header row repeats itself in the file multiple times. Here is an example:

```
name|address|amt_billed|service_date|ICD

data|data|data|data|data

data|data|data|data|data

data|data|data|data|data

name|address|amt_billed|service_date|ICD
```

I need to remove the second row of column headers without deleting the first row of headers. The code I have so far deletes any row that starts with "name" therefore removing the initial header row. I need to do this without using Pandas.

Here is my current code:

```
import os

fileDirectory = 'C:Input\\directory\\'

outputDirectory = 'C:Output\\directory\\'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDirectory):
    for file in files:
        with open(root + file, "r") as input:
            with open(outputDirectory + file, "w") as output:
                for line in input:
                    if not line.startswith('name'):
                        output.write(line)
```

Is there a way to ignore the first header row?

Comment: And the data can be duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way of doing it would be to check whether the first header line has been already copied to the output file, by using a boolean variable. Then all the other occurrences could be deleted:

```
import os

fileDirectory = 'C:Input\\directory\\'

outputDirectory = 'C:Output\\directory\\'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDirectory):
    for file in files:
        headerCopied = False
        with open(root + file, "r") as input:
            with open(outputDirectory + file, "w") as output:
                for line in input:
                    if not line.startswith('name'):
                        output.write(line)
                    else:
                        if not headerCopied:
                            output.write(line)
                            headerCopied = True
```

This should do the trick. Hope it helps.

Comment: lol... This is how you know it's a trivial solution: when two strangers come up with virtually the same thing.

Comment: While this answer is almost correct there is one edit. The headerCopied variable needs to be placed inside the loop so it gets set back to False during each iteration. Otherwise, only the first file will include the header row, it will be deleted from the other files.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just write the header line before removing the others? For example, why not just go:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDirectory):
    for file in files:
        with open(root + file, "r") as input:
            with open(outputDirectory + file, "w") as output:
                open.write("name|address|amt_billed|service_date|ICD")
                for line in input:
                    if not line.startswith('name'):
                        output.write(line)
```

That way it writes a single header line to the file, then adds every line that doesn't start with "name" (AKA is not a header) to the output file. Provided that the header string is static, is there a reason to not just programatically include the line in the output and then just not include any headers at all from the input file?

Comment: From the question, it sounds like OP already has the header text in the file, and he's trying to remove it. This will simply add another header to what is already there

Comment: No that won't, actually...? It prints one header line to the output, then it loops through the input file lines and prints any line that doesn't start with "name".

Comment: my bad -- I see that now.

Comment: All good, I didn't do a great job explaining my code either, probably didn't help much

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what you just said: ignore the first header row.

```
import os

fileDirectory = 'C:Input\\directory\\'

outputDirectory = 'C:Output\\directory\\'

firstHeaderRow = True
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDirectory):
    for file in files:
        with open(root + file, "r") as input:
            with open(outputDirectory + file, "w") as output:
                for line in input:
                    if not line.startswith('name'):
                        output.write(line)
                    elif firstHeaderRow:
                        output.write(line)
                        firstHeaderRow = False
```